# Handling CTRL-C in dummy shell

Tags: c, shell, signals, signal-handling, control-c

I'm writing a dummy shell that should not terminate when the user types ctrl-C but should just generate a new prompt line.  Currently, my shell does not terminate when I type ctrl-C but it still does not print the new prompt line.  Do you know why this is the case and how I can fix this?

My code is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

void INThandler(int);
static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}

void INThandler(int sig)
{
  printf("\n> ");
  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  }
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;


    printf("$dummyshell\n");
    signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
    while(1){

        printf("> ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);

    pid = fork();

        if (pid){      
            wait(&retStatus);
        }

        else {
            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }
    /*  pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
      setpgrp();
    else if (pid)
      pid = wait(&retStatus);
    else {
      if (execvp(args[0], args)){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(127);
      }
      }*/


    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) dont use `printf()` from within a signal handler; it is not signal-safe 2) take a look at `sigsetjmp`.

Comment: I looked up `sigsetjmp` but I do not understand how it will help?

Comment: It might help you to get back to the `printf("> ");` prompt in the main loop (which still needs a fflush() BTW) if a signal is detected.

Comment: I don't have a file stream, why would I need to use fflush?

Comment: The prompt string is not terminated by a '\n' and stdout will probably be line buffered. Without the fflush(), the prompt will just stay in the buffer (until there are enough of them)

Comment: Yes but what would I pass through fflush()?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass through fflush()" ?

Comment: fflush() needs an argument

Answer (score 0):

> but what would I pass through fflush()?

It would be

```
    fflush(stdout);
```

- but that is not needed because of the `fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)`.

> Output streams that refer to terminal devices are always line buffered
>   by  default;  pending  output  to such streams is written automatically
>   whenever an input stream that refers to a terminal device is read.

(See `man stdio`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the interrupt handler to jump into the while loop in your `main` function, instead of printing `"\>"`.

You can use `sigsetjmp` and `siglongjmp` for this. You might want to take at [1] for an example.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <signal.h>
#include  <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf  JumpBuffer;
void     INThandler(int);

void  main(void)
{
     signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
     while (1) {
          if (setjmp(JumpBuffer) == 0) {
             printf(">");
             /*...*/
          }
     }
}

void  INThandler(int  sig)
{
     signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
     signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
     longjmp(JumpBuffer, 1);
}
```

This was adapted from [2]. If you use `sigaction()`, `sigprocmask()`, or `sigsuspend()` you need to use the `siglongjmp` and `sigsetjmp` functions, respectively [3].

**Sources**:

- [1] https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/apis/siglngj.htm
- [2] http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/non-local-goto/sig-1.html
- [3] sigsetjmp - The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition