# Writing my own shell - trouble with handling ctrl+c (SIGINT) correctly

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, signal-handling

I am writing my own simple shell. One thing which I need to do is to control the SIGINT signal by remaining in the shell and just printing the prompt on a fresh line when ctrl+c is pressed. Currently, I have been able to handle the signal and the shell simply prints `^C` after the prompt. However, the cursor remains on the same line. What I would like to do instead is have the shell print `^C` after the prompt, move onto the next line and then print a fresh prompt.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109424/handling-ctrl-c-in-dummy-shell), which addresses the exact same issue. The problem with mine is that my `main` calls another function where the prompt loop is run. I have tried many different ways to try to implement the solution given on the link above, in both the main and the prompt loop function, but all with no luck. Here is my code so far:

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "MyShell.h"

void ctrl_C_handler();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    signal(SIGINT, ctrl_C_handler);
    my_shell_loop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void ctrl_C_handler() { 
    //Catches the SIGINT signal fine without anything happening in this function
    //I cannot figure out how to have MyShell print a fresh prompt on a new line 
    //after ctrl+C is pressed
}
```

**MyShellLoop.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "MyShell.h"

char *get_time();

void my_shell_loop() {
    char *line;
    char **args;
    int status;

    char *prompt = (char *) malloc(17);

    do {
        strcpy(prompt, get_time());
        strcat(prompt, " # ");
        printf("%s", prompt);
        line = read_command();
        args = split_command(line);
        status = execute_command(args);

        free(line);
        free(args);
    } while (status);

    free(prompt);
}
```

**EDIT**

Using:

```
void ctrl_C_handler() { 
    signal(SIGINT, ctrl_C_handler);
    printf("\n");
    my_shell_loop();
}
```

acts as desired the first time ctrl+c is pressed, but then acts as it did before for any further times it is pressed.

Comment: I really don't see anything that can be named "issue". Just perform one loop iteration with empty input. Yes, you will have to rearrange stuff to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That was one solution I too came up with, but I was not able to do perform a loop with no user input. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Take the loop content into a separate function. Or better to two - one for input, one for output. Then just call the one for output.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Inside my `ctrl_C_handler` function I simply printed a new line and then called `my_shell_loop()`. This works as desired the first time ctrl+c is pressed, but then if it is pressed again, it acts as it did previously

Comment: Well, after you have handled the signal once, you have to re-assign the handler again. Just put the `signal` line in the end of the handler itself

Comment: @EugeneSh. So you mean in `ctrl_C_handler()` move `signal(SIGINT, ctrl_C_handler)` from the start to the end of the function? I did this and it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: In the code posted you don't have it neither in the start nor in the end. Update: NO! Don't call loop from the handler! It is getting stuck there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, see the edit at the end of my post

Comment: 1) don't call `printf()` from within a signal handler, it is not signal safe. 2) you need `sigsetjmp()`

Comment: You link to another very similar article, where both the `sigsetjmp()` and the *don't printf from a signalhandler* are given. Have you actually **read** that question and answers?

Answer (score 0):

`signal` attaches a handler only for the first appropriate signal that is received. After that invocation, the handler is detached. A common method is to have the handler reattach itself as in `int foo() { signal(SIGINT, &foo); do_the_stuff(); }`.

However, [`signal` is non-portable](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal). POSIX recommends using [`sigaction`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) instead.

Comment: Your first solution isn't possible in my case as `signal` is called in `main` - am I correct in saying this?

Comment: You'll still call signal the first time, in main or wherever, just once. Every time the signal is caught thereafter, the handler will reattach itself by calling signal in its own body.

Comment: I'm really struggling to get anywhere with this due to my poor undertanding of the `signal` function. I have my `main` method just as it is above, calling `signal(SIGINT, ctrl_C_handler)`. Then I have `void ctrl_C_handler() { signal(SIGINT, ctrl_C_handler) }`, but it is still only printing `^C` without printing the new prompt. What else do I have to add to this?

Comment: When you call signal(SIGINT, &foo), the OS will remember to call foo when the process gets a SIGINT. Wherever your program is in its execution, it will be as if foo() was called then and there. When foo() finishes, the process will go back to doing whatever it was doing. But the OS will only remember to do this once, so you have to keep reminding it after every time. The simplest way is to just have foo() do it.